# jpackage linux creates insufficient desktop file

Tags: java, linux, jpackage

I just started using jpackage and it is a really great tool. One single step takes a lot of work off my shoulders. The more surprised I am about something that looks hardcoded and cannot be customized?

JPackage automatically generates the launcher (`lib/<application>.desktop` file), and the deb package automatically installs it such that all users can launch the application. But as soon as it is launched, another icon pops up in unity. I expected that the existing icon is marked as running.

According to [Ubuntu DEB installer makes all Java applications have the same icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941454/ubuntu-deb-installer-makes-all-java-applications-have-the-same-icon) we just need to ensure the .desktop file contains the correct `StartupWMClass`. Using xprop I found out this value is based on the fully qualified class name responsible for the window - which makes absolute sense.

So how can I tell jpackage which StartupWMClass to set in the generated .desktop file?

Edit: To complement Bodo's comment I will show how I call jpackage. In fact I am not running a command line myself - instead I am using the maven plugin configured as:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.akman</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jpackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        
          <dest>target</dest>
          <name>OoliteCommunicator</name>
          <type>PLATFORM</type>
          <appversion>${project.version}</appversion>
          <description>Oolite Communicator is an add-on for Oolite to allow multiplayer interaction. (check http://oolite.org)</description>
          <vendor>Hiran</vendor>
          <icon>target/classes/com/mycompany/oolitecommunicator/ui/Communicator_Logo_Icon.png</icon>
          <input>target/dist</input>
          <mainjar>OoliteCommunicator-${project.version}.jar</mainjar>
          <mainclass>com.mycompany.oolitecommunicator.Main</mainclass>
                        
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

What I can see during the maven build is this output, which I believe to be the command line generated internally when the plugin invokes jpackage. The last line may be the invocation already, and whenever I check after the build there is no file /home/hiran/NetBeansProjects/OoliteCommunicator/target/jpackage.opts. I can only assume it's content was logged just before.

```
# jpackage
--dest /home/hiran/NetBeansProjects/OoliteCommunicator/target
--app-version '1.0-20211220-090022'
--description 'Oolite Communicator is an add-on for Oolite to allow multiplayer interaction. (check http://oolite.org)'
--name 'OoliteCommunicator'
--vendor 'Hiran'
--icon /home/hiran/NetBeansProjects/OoliteCommunicator/target/classes/com/mycompany/oolitecommunicator/ui/Communicator_Logo_Icon.png
--input /home/hiran/NetBeansProjects/OoliteCommunicator/target/dist
--main-jar 'OoliteCommunicator-1.0-20211220-090022.jar'
--main-class com.mycompany.oolitecommunicator.Main
/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/bin/jpackage @/home/hiran/NetBeansProjects/OoliteCommunicator/target/jpackage.opts
```

Finaly I get a deb package with this desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OoliteCommunicator
Comment=Oolite Communicator is an add-on for Oolite to allow multiplayer interaction. (check http://oolite.org)
Exec=/opt/oolitecommunicator/bin/OoliteCommunicator
Icon=/opt/oolitecommunicator/lib/OoliteCommunicator.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Unknown
MimeType=
```

and I fixed the bhaviour by manually adding the line

```
StartupWMClass=com-mycompany-oolitecommunicator-Main
```

So my workaround is to add this line to both

- /opt/oolitecommunicator/lib/oolitecommunicator-OoliteCommunicator.desktop
- /usr/share/applications/oolitecommunicator-OoliteCommunicator.desktop

after the deb has been installed. Not that easy as jpackage was intended for I guess...

Comment: Please show in your question the complete `jpackage` command you are using, and if you use `@filename`, the contents of the file.

Comment: I added more information. Sorry that I cannot provide the command line directly.

Comment: The contents of `/home/hiran/NetBeansProjects/OoliteCommunicator/target/jpackage.opts` may also be important. I suggest to try `--main-class class name`, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html#options-for-creating-the-application-launchers

Comment: I added the information as you suggested. My POM is updated, the log when calling jpackage is updated, but the resulting .desktop file is the same. :-(

Comment: You should add the information *to the question* what exactly you added which did not help to get the `StartupWMClass` line in the launcher file. If you don't see a file `/home/hiran/NetBeansProjects/OoliteCommunicator/target/jpackage.opts` then this file probably gets generated automatically before running the command and deleted afterwards. Sorry, my suggestion was based on the documentation only. I can only suggest to run `jpackage` manually and experiment with the options to find out if you can somehow get it to create the .desktop file as required. Then proceed to the `maven` integration.

Comment: The point is: by looking at the docs I do not see any hint for StartupWMClass. By looking at the source (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.jpackage/linux/classes/jdk/jpackage/internal) neither code nor template mention StartupWMClass. It seems to not exist in the whole tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found a possibility to have the right packaging.

You need to override the JPackage internal template and provide your own .desktop file. This can be done by [overriding JPackage resources](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6).

It means you create a resource folder with the correct .desktop file inside, specify the resource folder on the JPackage command line and the correct package will be created.