JPackage via maven and missing .desktop file and icon
pom.xml
I have a set of modular maven projects and a parent pom project. Under the parent there's also a converter.jlink project. In its pom I use the maven-jlink-plugin to create a runnable image in its target folder. It runs fine but now I want to package it up as a deb install file. I've added this to the converter.jlink pom:
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.akman</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <dest>target/dist/</dest>
        <name>Converter</name>
        <appversion>${project.version}</appversion>
        <type>PLATFORM</type> <!-- deb -->
        <icon>src/main/resources/converter.svg</icon>
        <vendor>Footeware.ca</vendor>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <runtimeimage>target/maven-jlink/default/</runtimeimage>
        <linuxshortcut>true</linuxshortcut>
        <linuxdebmaintainer>CraigFoote@gmail.com</linuxdebmaintainer>
        <licensefile>src/main/resources/gpl-3.0.txt</licensefile>
        <resourcedir>src/main/resources/</resourcedir>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jpackage-image</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jpackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

The converter
The jlink's src/main/resources contains an app icon, a license file, and a converter.desktop file that I read somewhere had to be added via "resourcedir" to get found. The packaging seems to work - I've used "verbose" true but I see next to nothing from the maven output of jpackage. There is a deb file created that installs into /opt fine. But my $HOME/.local/share/applications folder doesn't get a converter.desktop file created. I've used "linuxshortcut" true but I see no shortcut. I've added an "icon" directive but I don't know where to look for it. It's not in $HOME/.local/share/icons. I've tried running jpackage on the cli but I'm getting the same results. What am I missing or doing wrong?

https://github.com/life888888/JPdfBookmarks_INSTALLER_BUILD , search postinst , find xdg-desktop-menu install /opt/jpdfbookmarks/lib/jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks.desktop

@life888888 does it mean a new file postinst has to be created with the instructions?

I believe so but do I also need a .control file? But I can't get anything in src/main/resources to be put into the deb file. I'm specifying resourcedir but the icon, .desktop and now control and postinst files do not get packaged into the deb. So the postinst can't find them.

(1) I suggest you first use the command mode to generate the deb file in Terminal. Instead of using the Maven method from the beginning. Using the command mode you can directly see the output response and quickly adjust the parameters. (2) If you have succeeded You have created a deb file. It is recommended that you install your deb file first, then go to the installation directory and compare each file in it.

In addition, you can see my JPdfBookmarks_INSTALLER_BUILD project, which is an independent project that packages another JPdfBookmarks project into an Installer project. For the sake of simplicity, it is simply .sh or .bat to execute the entire jpackage packaging operation.

@banan3'14 postinst will read file from your app install folder (/opt/yourApp) like /opt/yourApp/lib/your-app.desktop.

/opt/converter/lib/ doesn't exist after install.

I've been in a similar situation. Here's what saved my day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420618/jpackage-linux-creates-insufficient-desktop-file/70794491#70794491

Specific Answer for https://github.com/CraigFoote/ca.footeware.swing.converter
Only Modify sub poject: converter.app
converter.app Tree
converter.app
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        ├── jpackage-data (1) DIR
        │   ├── converter.app.jpackage.settings (2)
        │   ├── converter.mime.properties (3)
        │   └── linuxOverride (4) DIR
        │       ├── converter.desktop (5)
        │       ├── postinst (6)
        │       └── postrm   (7)
        └── resources-extra  (8) DIR
            ├── gpl-3.0.txt  (9)
            └── images       (10) DIR
                └── converter_32.png (11)

converter.app.jpackage.settings
The parameter can not put direct to pom.xml,
because mail format have < and >
--copyright "Copyright (c) 2024 Craig Foote <CraigFoote@gmail.com>"
--vendor "Craig Foote <CraigFoote@gmail.com>"

converter.mime.properties
You can modify for your need.
mime-type=application/txt
extension=txt
description=TXT

converter.desktop
Append %f in Exec=/opt/converter/bin/converter
Let System can let this app in Open With App List.
[Desktop Entry]
Name=converter
Comment=An application with a set of tab panels each doing some sort of conversion.
Exec=/opt/converter/bin/converter %f
Icon=/opt/converter/lib/converter.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility
MimeType=application/txt

postinst

it will run after deb install finish.
add converter to /usr/bin/
you can open terminal in any directory , then run command converter (Like set PATH to your app folder)

#!/bin/sh
# postinst script for jpdfbookmarks
#
# see: dh_installdeb(1)

set -e

# summary of how this script can be called:
#        * <postinst> `configure' <most-recently-configured-version>
#        * <old-postinst> `abort-upgrade' <new version>
#        * <conflictor's-postinst> `abort-remove' `in-favour' <package>
#          <new-version>
#        * <postinst> `abort-remove'
#        * <deconfigured's-postinst> `abort-deconfigure' `in-favour'
#          <failed-install-package> <version> `removing'
#          <conflicting-package> <version>
# for details, see https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ or
# the debian-policy package

case "$1" in
    configure)
xdg-desktop-menu install /opt/converter/lib/converter-converter.desktop
        # register /usr/bin/converter as a converter in the alternatives system
        update-alternatives \
            --install \
                /usr/bin/converter \
                converter \
                /opt/converter/bin/converter \
                50
    ;;

    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0

postrm

it will run remove deb install finish.

#!/bin/sh
# postrm script for jpdfbookmarks
#
# see: dh_installdeb(1)

set -e

# summary of how this script can be called:
#        * <postrm> `remove'
#        * <postrm> `purge'
#        * <old-postrm> `upgrade' <new-version>
#        * <new-postrm> `failed-upgrade' <old-version>
#        * <new-postrm> `abort-install'
#        * <new-postrm> `abort-install' <old-version>
#        * <new-postrm> `abort-upgrade' <old-version>
#        * <disappearer's-postrm> `disappear' <overwriter>
#          <overwriter-version>
# for details, see https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ or
# the debian-policy package

case "$1" in
    purge|remove)
           update-alternatives --remove converter /usr/bin/converter || true 
    ;;
    
    upgrade|failed-upgrade|abort-install|abort-upgrade|disappear)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "postrm called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0

gpl-3.0.txt

copy gpl-3.0.txt from converter.jlink/src/main/resources/gpl-3.0.txt

converter_32.png

copy converter.svg from converter.jlink/src/main/resources/converter.svg

Please note that jpackage --icon does not accept svg(converter.svg), so we must convert svg to png file.
My method for converting svg files to png files:
# install tool: inkscape
sudo apt install inkscape

# convert `converter.svg` to `converter_32.png`

inkscape converter.svg \
  --export-width=32 \
  --export-height=32 \
  --export-png=converter_32.png



delete converter.svg only keep converter_32.png

put converter_32.png in converter.app/src/main/resources-extra/images
pom.xml
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>converter.app</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>ca.footeware.swing</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter.parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../converter.parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GNU General Public License (GPL) version 3.0</name>
            <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.footeware.swing</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter.spi</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <!--<arg>-verbose</arg> -->
                        <!--<arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg> -->
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>converter.app.Converter</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <built-by/>
                            <!-- add empty for not add user name -->
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                            <App-Version>${project.version}</App-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/jpackage-files/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/images/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources-extra</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>converter.app.Converter</mainClass>
                            <id>converterapp</id>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                    <extraJvmArguments>
                        -Duser.language=en
                        -Duser.country=US
                        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                        -Xms128M
                        -Xmx756M
                    </extraJvmArguments>
                    <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                    <useWildcardClassPath>true</useWildcardClassPath>
                    <binFileExtensions>
                        <!--<unix>.sh</unix> -->
                    </binFileExtensions>
                    <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jpackage-linux-deb</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>jpackage</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>@${project.basedir}/src/main/jpackage-data/converter.app.jpackage.settings
                                </argument>
                                <argument>--name</argument>
                                <argument>converter</argument>
                                <argument>--input</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib</argument>
                                <argument>--license-file</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib/gpl-3.0.txt</argument>
                                <argument>--icon</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib/images/converter_32.png</argument>
                                <argument>--main-jar</argument>
                                <argument>converter.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</argument>
                                <argument>--description</argument>
                                <argument>An application with a set of tab panels each doing some sort of conversion.
                                </argument>
                                <argument>--app-version</argument>
                                <argument>0.0.1</argument>
                                <argument>--linux-app-release</argument>
                                <argument>snapshot-1</argument>
                                <argument>--add-modules</argument>
                                <argument>java.base,java.desktop</argument>
                                <argument>--file-associations</argument>
                                <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/jpackage-data/converter.mime.properties</argument>
                                <argument>--java-options</argument>
                                <argument>-ms64m</argument>
                                <argument>--java-options</argument>
                                <argument>-mx512m</argument>
                                <argument>--linux-shortcut</argument>
                                <argument>--linux-app-category</argument>
                                <argument>Utility</argument>
                                <argument>--linux-menu-group</argument>
                                <argument>Utility</argument>
                                <argument>--about-url</argument>
                                <argument>http://Footeware.ca</argument>
                                <argument>--resource-dir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.basedir}/src/main/jpackage-data/linuxOverride</argument>

                            </arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>

Build
mvn clean package exec:exec@jpackage-linux-deb

Now you can find output file in target\converter_0.0.1-snapshot-1_amd64.deb
Install deb
sudo dpkg -i converter_0.0.1-snapshot-1_amd64.deb

Check install (For Ubuntu Desktop UI)
Check Desktop UI

In your app start point , you can find converter Icon.

(relate to converter.desktop file)



then you can click and run.
Terminal Check you can call it from any directory
# in home (`~/`)
~$ converter

# in Downloads (`~/Downloads`)
~$ cd Downloads
~/Downloads$ converter


Check Open With
In File Explorer , Select XXX.txt , mouse Right Click , popup menu Open With Other Application

Find your application in List


Select converter, then click Select
Remove your app
sudo apt remove -y converter

My Package
converter.app/target/appassembler
├── bin (NOT IMPORTANT)
│   ├── converterapp
│   └── converterapp.bat
└── lib (YOUR APP)
    ├── converter.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── converter.spi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── gpl-3.0.txt
    └── images
        └── converter_32.png

pom.xml - plugin maven-jar-plugin

set jar as executable jar (set mainClass)
add classpath (other dependency jar) to jar

pom.xml - plugin maven-resources-plugin

copy gpl-3.0.txt to /target/appassembler/lib
copy converter_32.png to /target/appassembler/lib/images

pom.xml - plugin appassembler-maven-plugin

create target/appassembler
we will only use then target/appassembler/lib

target/appassembler
├── bin
│   ├── converterapp
│   └── converterapp.bat
└── lib
    ├── converter.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── converter.spi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── gpl-3.0.txt
    └── images
        └── converter_32.png

pom.xml - plugin exec-maven-plugin

run jpackage command

Same command like this:
jpackage \
  --name converter \
  --input target/appassembler/lib \
  --license-file "target/appassembler/lib/gpl-3.0.txt" \
  --icon         "target/appassembler/lib/images/converter_32.png" \
  --main-jar converter.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  --description "An application with a set of tab panels each doing some sort of conversion." \
  --vendor "Craig Foote <CraigFoote@gmail.com>" \
  --copyright "Copyright (c) 2024 Craig Foote <CraigFoote@gmail.com>" \
  --app-version 0.0.1 \
  --linux-app-release snapshot-1 \
  --add-modules java.base,java.desktop \
  --file-associations src/main/jpackage-data/converter.mime.properties \
  --java-options "-ms64m" \
  --java-options "-mx512m" \
  --linux-shortcut \
  --linux-app-category "Utility" \
  --linux-menu-group "Utility" \
  --about-url "http://Footeware.ca" \
  --resource-dir src/main/jpackage-data/linuxOverride

pom.xml use jpackage-maven-plugin
use jpackage-maven-plugin
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>converter.app</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>ca.footeware.swing</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter.parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../converter.parent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>GNU General Public License (GPL) version 3.0</name>
            <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.footeware.swing</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter.spi</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                        <!--<arg>-verbose</arg> -->
                        <!--<arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg> -->
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>converter.app.Converter</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <built-by/>
                            <!-- add empty for not add user name -->
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                            <App-Version>${project.version}</App-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/jpackage-files/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/images/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources-extra</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>converter.app.Converter</mainClass>
                            <id>converterapp</id>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                    <extraJvmArguments>
                        -Duser.language=en
                        -Duser.country=US
                        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                        -Xms128M
                        -Xmx756M
                    </extraJvmArguments>
                    <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                    <useWildcardClassPath>true</useWildcardClassPath>
                    <binFileExtensions>
                        <!--<unix>.sh</unix> -->
                    </binFileExtensions>
                    <repositoryName>lib</repositoryName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.akman</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>            
                        <configuration>
                        <name>converter</name>
                        <dest>${project.build.directory}/</dest>
                        <input>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib</input>
                        <licensefile>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib/gpl-3.0.txt</licensefile>
                        <icon>${project.build.directory}/appassembler/lib/images/converter.png</icon>
                        <mainjar>converter.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</mainjar>
                        <argument>--</argument>
                        <description>An application with a set of tab panels each doing some sort of conversion.</description>
                        <appversion>0.0.1</appversion>
                        <linuxapprelease>snapshot-1</linuxapprelease>
                        <addmodules>java.base,java.desktop</addmodules>

                        <fileassociations>${project.basedir}/src/main/jpackage-data/converter.mime.properties</fileassociations>
                        <javaoptions>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ms64m -mx512m</javaoptions>
                        <linuxshortcut></linuxshortcut>
                        <linuxappcategory>Utility</linuxappcategory>
                        <linuxmenugroup>Utility</linuxmenugroup>
                        <abouturl>http://Footeware.ca</abouturl>
                        <resourcedir>${project.basedir}/src/main/jpackage-data/linuxOverride</resourcedir>
                        <vendor>Craig Foote &lt;CraigFoote@gmail.com&gt;</vendor>
                        <copyright>Copyright (c) 2024 Craig Foote &lt;CraigFoote@gmail.com&gt;</copyright>

                        </configuration>

             </plugin>                   
             
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>

build
mvn clean package jpackage:jpackage

Check mapping to jpackage command
mvn -e -X clean package jpackage:jpackage

it will show command , you can check
[DEBUG] 
# jpackage
--dest /your-path/ca.footeware.swing.converter-master/converter.app/target
--app-version '0.0.1'
--copyright 'Copyright (c) 2024 Craig Foote <CraigFoote@gmail.com>'
--description 'An application with a set of tab panels each doing some sort of conversion.'
--name 'converter'
--vendor 'Craig Foote <CraigFoote@gmail.com>'
--icon /your-path/ca.footeware.swing.converter-master/converter.app/target/appassembler/lib/images/converter.png
--input /your-path/ca.footeware.swing.converter-master/converter.app/target/appassembler/lib
--main-jar 'converter.app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
--java-options '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -ms64m -mx512m'
--file-associations /your-path/ca.footeware.swing.converter-master/converter.app/src/main/jpackage-data/converter.mime.properties
--license-file /your-path/ca.footeware.swing.converter-master/converter.app/target/appassembler/lib/gpl-3.0.txt
--resource-dir /your-path/ca.footeware.swing.converter-master/converter.app/src/main/jpackage-data/linuxOverride
--linux-menu-group 'Utility'
--linux-app-release 'snapshot-1'
--linux-app-category 'Utility'
--add-modules java.base,java.desktop


Now you can use maven command:
in converter.app
# version 1 pom.xml - use exec plugin
mvn clean package exec:exec@jpackage-linux-deb

# version 2 pom.xml -use jpackage plugin
mvn clean package jpackage:jpackage


And you don't need converter.jlink
I still have to remind you again why I recommend using the command line command jpackage to test. After the test command is successful, you can switch to the pom.xml exec plugin setting. Only when you use the command do you find that jpackage --icon does not accept svg files.
Please note that some file names are standardized and must be consistent with your launcher name. (this example: launcher name is converter) Please refer to the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/packaging-tool-user-guide.pdf (Packaging Tool User's Guide).

My Install Project For Linux Deb
https://github.com/life888888/JPdfBookmarks_INSTALLER_BUILD
├── build-installer-deb-3.0.2.sh
├── build-installer-deb-pre-setup.sh
├── jpdfbookmarks_3.0.2-snapshot-1_amd64.deb
├── jpdfbookmarks-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz
├── jpdfbookmarks.app.jpackage.settings
├── jpdfbookmarks_cli.linux.launcher
├── jpdfbookmarks.linux.jpackage.settings
├── jpdfbookmarks.mime.properties
├── linuxOverride
│   ├── jpdfbookmarks_cli.desktop
│   ├── jpdfbookmarks.desktop
│   ├── postinst
│   └── postrm
│
└── jpdfbookmarks (*this is your java application*) 
    ├── conf
    ├── COPYING
    ├── jpdfbookmarks.ico *
    ├── jpdfbookmarks.jar
    ├── jpdfbookmarks.png *
    ├── lib
    │   ├── bcmail-jdk16-1.45.jar
    ....
    │   └── xmpbox-2.0.22.jar
    └── splash.png *

jpdfbookmarks (this is your java application)
It should be packaged and configured to run in an environment with Java Runtime.)
Please note that your ico and png files must be placed in your java application directory. (My exampe: jpdfbookmarks.ico, jpdfbookmarks.png,splash.png)
build-installer-deb-pre-setup.sh
You can ignore - Install SDKMan and install JDK
build-installer-deb-3.0.2.sh (Main install)
# Build jpdfbookmarks installer - deb - 3.0.2
...
cd jpdfbookmarks

## download jpdfbookmarks.ico
## download jpdfbookmarks/splash.png

cd ..

jpackage \
  @jpdfbookmarks.app.jpackage.settings \
  @jpdfbookmarks.linux.jpackage.settings  \
 --add-launcher jpdfbookmarks_cli=jpdfbookmarks_cli.linux.launcher  \
 --linux-app-release snapshot-1 \
 --linux-deb-maintainer "Flaviano Petrocchi<flavianopetrocchi@gmail.com>" \
 --app-version 3.0.2 \
 --add-modules  java.base,java.datatransfer,java.desktop,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.prefs,java.sql,java.xml

...

jpdfbookmarks.app.jpackage.settings
--name jpdfbookmarks
--input jpdfbookmarks
--main-jar jpdfbookmarks.jar
--copyright "Copyright (c) 2008 2009 2010 Flaviano Petrocchi <flavianopetrocchi@gmail.com>"
--license-file jpdfbookmarks/COPYING
--file-associations "jpdfbookmarks.mime.properties"
--java-options "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$APPDIR/conf/jpdfbookmarks.logging.properties"
--java-options "-splash:$APPDIR/splash.png"
--java-options "-ms64m"
--java-options "-mx512m"

Note:

--input jpdfbookmarks , replace jpdfbookmarks to  your java application folder.
--main-jar jpdfbookmarks.jar , replace jpdfbookmarks.jar to your executeable jar.
--file-associations "jpdfbookmarks.mime.properties" , let your system know open with

jpdfbookmarks.linux.jpackage.settings
--linux-shortcut
--linux-app-category Office
--linux-menu-group "Office"
--about-url "http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.com/"
--icon "jpdfbookmarks/jpdfbookmarks.png"
--resource-dir linuxOverride


your icon image: --icon "jpdfbookmarks/jpdfbookmarks.png", put your icon image in your application folder
something add :  --resource-dir linuxOverride

jpdfbookmarks.mime.properties
mime-type=application/pdf
extension=pdf
description=PDF

Please modify the content according to your needs.
postinst
#!/bin/sh
# postinst script for jpdfbookmarks
#
# see: dh_installdeb(1)

set -e

# summary of how this script can be called:
#        * <postinst> `configure' <most-recently-configured-version>
#        * <old-postinst> `abort-upgrade' <new version>
#        * <conflictor's-postinst> `abort-remove' `in-favour' <package>
#          <new-version>
#        * <postinst> `abort-remove'
#        * <deconfigured's-postinst> `abort-deconfigure' `in-favour'
#          <failed-install-package> <version> `removing'
#          <conflicting-package> <version>
# for details, see https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ or
# the debian-policy package

case "$1" in
    configure)
xdg-desktop-menu install /opt/jpdfbookmarks/lib/jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks.desktop
xdg-mime install /opt/jpdfbookmarks/lib/jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks-MimeInfo.xml
xdg-desktop-menu install /opt/jpdfbookmarks/lib/jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks_cli.desktop
        # register /usr/bin/jpdfbookmarks as a jpdfbookmarks in the alternatives system
        update-alternatives \
            --install \
                /usr/bin/jpdfbookmarks \
                jpdfbookmarks \
                /opt/jpdfbookmarks/bin/jpdfbookmarks \
                50 
        # register /usr/bin/jpdfbookmarks_cli as a jpdfbookmarks_cli in the alternatives system
        update-alternatives \
            --install \
                /usr/bin/jpdfbookmarks_cli \
                jpdfbookmarks_cli \
                /opt/jpdfbookmarks/bin/jpdfbookmarks_cli \
                50      
    ;;

    abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-deconfigure)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0

After .deb install, will run this file (postinst).

install desktop : xdg-desktop-menu install /opt/jpdfbookmarks/lib/jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks.desktop
install mime type: xdg-mime install /opt/jpdfbookmarks/lib/jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks-MimeInfo.xml
add your application link to /usr/bin/your-app-exe

update-alternatives \
  --install \
  /usr/bin/jpdfbookmarks \
  jpdfbookmarks \
  /opt/jpdfbookmarks/bin/jpdfbookmarks \
  50

Optional, add this paragraph, just so that you can enter your-app in the terminal and then execute it. (Similar to adding PATH, because your-app link to /usr/bin)
postrm
After .deb remove, will run this file (postrm).
#!/bin/sh
# postrm script for jpdfbookmarks
#
# see: dh_installdeb(1)

set -e

# summary of how this script can be called:
#        * <postrm> `remove'
#        * <postrm> `purge'
#        * <old-postrm> `upgrade' <new-version>
#        * <new-postrm> `failed-upgrade' <old-version>
#        * <new-postrm> `abort-install'
#        * <new-postrm> `abort-install' <old-version>
#        * <new-postrm> `abort-upgrade' <old-version>
#        * <disappearer's-postrm> `disappear' <overwriter>
#          <overwriter-version>
# for details, see https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ or
# the debian-policy package

case "$1" in
    purge|remove)
           update-alternatives --remove jpdfbookmarks /usr/bin/jpdfbookmarks || true 
           update-alternatives --remove jpdfbookmarks_cli /usr/bin/jpdfbookmarks_cli || true            
    ;;
    
    upgrade|failed-upgrade|abort-install|abort-upgrade|disappear)
    ;;

    *)
        echo "postrm called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0

jpdfbookmarks.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=jpdfbookmarks
Comment=jpdfbookmarks
Exec=/opt/jpdfbookmarks/bin/jpdfbookmarks %f
Icon=/opt/jpdfbookmarks/lib/jpdfbookmarks.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Office
MimeType=application/pdf

After Deb Install
└── opt
    └── jpdfbookmarks
        ├── bin
        │   └── jpdfbookmarks (execuate file , create by jpackage)
        └── lib
            ├── app (your original application folder)
            │   ├── jpdfbookmarks.ico (your icon)
            │   ├── jpdfbookmarks.jar
            │   ├── jpdfbookmarks.png (your icon)
            ..........
            │   └── splash.png
            ├── jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks.desktop (your .desktop)
            ├── jpdfbookmarks-jpdfbookmarks-MimeInfo.xml (your mime file)
            ├── jpdfbookmarks.png (your icon)
            ├── libapplauncher.so (create by jpackage)
            └── runtime (create by jpackage)
                ├── conf
                ├── legal
                └── lib (Your-Java-Runtime)


Ignore any about jpdfbookmarks_cli.xxx

Wow that's a great answer, thanks for responding. However my problem seems to be that the "app" folder is not created. Maybe because I'm building from a jlinked application rather than an executable jar?

https://pastebin.com/Qnnyutve my latest project structure and build result.

(1) Your maven-jlink will correspond to my answer After Deb Install -> runtime (create by jpackage) (2) src/main/java/module-info.java , I don’t have this. When using jpackage, jpackage does not care whether your application was compiled with JDK 8 or JDK 11.

(1) my maven jlink has been working from the start. It's the jpackage I'm having a problem with. (2) I have several of these module-info's linked together to make a modular application that runs fine from /opt where the deb installer copies it. Specifically I'm looking for the icon and desktop file and for them to work with postinst, they have to be packaged with the deb - and they're not.

I find it frustrating that when my bounty expired this answer was marked correct. It did not fix my problem!

Where is your project in github ?

Step1 : Prepare a App Directory. and it can be run. and include all jar, config files. Step2: try to use command build your xxx.deb. not use maven plugin build your xxx.deb.

https://github.com/CraigFoote/ca.footeware.swing.converter - it's just a toy project to use modules and maven to build a deb. I guess your suggestion to build w/o maven is an answer but the question specifically stated via maven so... and I'm sure someone out there has done this. Just a little XML after all :) Anyway, I've put this on the back burner now. Thanks for the input!

@CraigFoote Based on the project on your github, I will provide an answer specifically for your project.

Add new version pom.xml use jpackage plugin.
